# Prettyphoto popup position issue

Tags: prettyphoto

I've a problem with the position of the popup in Prettyphoto.
When I open the first image the popup is in the center of the page but when I click on next the top and left value becomes 0. If I move the mouse, the popup come back in the center of the page.

What's the problem?

Comment: Code code code code code code code. Code?

Comment: I use Prettyphoto 3.1.5...I didn't modified the code.

Comment: Implementation code? Either way, I've never used PrettyPhoto, but it looks archaic. Support for Firefox 3.0+ but also Chrome 10+ (meaning FF 3+ but not an earlier webkit than Chrome 10) and IE 6 (dropped, so now 7?), with (clearing throat) Safari 3+? A lot doesn't add up there. I wouldn't be surprised if it weren't just outdated software.

Comment: ... Although, it should be noted that all the demos work in Chrome 38 on linux, so there's that. On top of implemenation code, browser/os?

Comment: The problem is in Firefox, Safari, chrome, Ios, etc

Comment: If the issue is apparent on all browsers, but not in the demo code, then it's likely your code (or something conflicting). I would recommend posting your implementation code and screening all of the rest of your code (both in-house and 3rd party) for potentially conflicting code. No one can help you with essentially no information.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, try disabling animate-enhanced/animate-enhanced.min.js if you have it in your page.